# Convert Perl Script to Executable file packaging YAML file in executable used by perl script

Tags: perl

I have small perl script **test.pl**. This perl script uses input as YAML file **database.yml**
To convert these perl script into executable, I run following command shown below.

**pp -o -x teste.exe test.pl**.

It creates executable but when i try to run this executable it throws error that database.yml file not found in that directory.

How can i ensure that executable includes YAML file while creating the exe of perl script?

Note :- I am using perl verison 5.8 in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `-a` switch :

```
pp -a database.yml -o -x teste.exe test.pl
```

From `pp` documentation :

```
   -a, --addfile=FILE|DIR
       Add an extra file into the package.  If the file is a directory, recursively add all files inside that directory, with links turned into actual files.

       By default, files are placed under "/" inside the package with their original names.  You may override this by appending the target filename after a ";", like this:

           % pp -a "old_filename.txt;new_filename.txt"
           % pp -a "old_dirname;new_dirname"

       You may specify "-a" multiple times.
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. Do i need to include any extra specific perl module so that i can use this stuff or is in built in the default perl package

Comment: What error message do you have ? How do you open the yaml file in your application ? I'm not sur about your `pp` line, from documentation it should be more something like `pp -x -o teste.exe test.pl` with the -a added. The -x should take care of including the extra module YAML needed as it is not core Perl, otherwise force it with `-M YAML` or `-M YAML::XS`. On an unrelated note, perl 5.8 is really old now, please find a way to upgrade if you can.